# Running az cli command in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to automate the transferring of files into my Azure Storage. I'm using the following script.

```
az storage account keys list -g ****V2 -n *****estx
az storage blob upload-batch --source $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/out/build --destination `$web --account-key *****agnqUDzwNe/gOIAzsQ== --account-name *****estx
```

This works, but I don't want to add the `--acount-key`. When I try to retrieve the account key by using `az storage account keys list` I get:

> Please run 'az login' to setup account.

I'm using a Azure PowerShell (Preview) task version 4.

How can I substitute my current account key with something generated?

Comment: Use az cli task rather than powershell task.

Answer (score 1):

Running [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) Task will authenticate using [`Connect-AzAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-2.4.0)

You should use [Azure Cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) Task. It will authenticate using [`az login`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest).

Comment: I tried but running `az storage blob upload-batch` returns `The specifed resource name contains invalid characters. ErrorCode: InvalidResourceName` while in the Azure Powershell the line works fine.

Comment: Could you add some quotes around the string parameters ?

Comment: It was the `'$web`. Changing it to `$web` fixed the above issue.